# Specify device serial using ADB_DEVICE_ARG (RuntimeError)

Tags: android, automated-tests, calabash, circleci, calabash-android

I am running a Calabash-android test on CirecleCi. And on running the test I am getting the error response

```
It looks like your app is no longer running. 
It could be because of a crash or because your test script shuts it down.
Scenario: Home page and navigate to the registration page
                                                                                             # features/my_first.feature:3
More than one device connected. Specify device serial using   ADB_DEVICE_ARG (RuntimeError)
./features/support/app_installation_hooks.rb:18:in `Before'
App did not start (RuntimeError)
./features/support/app_life_cycle_hooks.rb:5:in `Before'
```

I install the apk on adb by using the command

> - adb -s emulator-5554 install "`pwd`/Test.apk"

But even  after that getting the above error. Since it is automated I can't go for the **calabash-android console** command. Is there any alternative to fix the issue. All kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Are there more than 1 device connected? If so does there need to be? Just to establish if disconnecting an emulator or device would solve this for you...

Comment: No. There exist only one device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is more than one device (or emulator) connected, you need to set an environment variable for ADB_DEVICE_ARG on the machine the code is running on.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue with the help of the following steps

```
- adb shell input keyevent 82 
- adb -s emulator-5554 install "`pwd`/Test.apk"
- export ADB_DEVICE_ARG=emulator-5554
```

Here the first one is to unlock the emulator. I guess missing this code does not allow the installation of apk file on the emulator. And after that, as @alannichols said I have exported the ADB_DEVICE_ARG  and thus, it is working.